# Set DATETIME field to zero date in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord

I have a Rails application that is managing a MySQL database through ActiveRecord. I have a DATETIME column in that database that I would like to set to the [zero date](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/using-date.html). (Not NULL, the zero date. Scroll down that page to see what I mean.)

Seems simple enough, but I cannot figure out how to make this happen without using raw SQL.

Here are a few of the things I have already tried:

- `field = 0` (fails with ActiveRecord error `Column 'field' cannot be null`)
- `field = "0000-00-00"` (fails with error `undefined method 'year' for nil:NilClass`)
- `field = DateTime.parse("0000-00-00")` (fails with DateTime error `invalid date`)

Is there a way to do this through ActiveRecord, or will I be forced to use raw SQL for this?

**EDIT:** I am not allowed to alter the structure of my SQL database to fix this. It's a work thing...

Comment: you have some kind of validation on the field.? one thing you can try is after updating the column with the value i.e `0` do this `object.save(validate: false)` this should save the object without throwing errors.

Comment: Have you tried using the `default` option in your Migration? Like `t.datetime :datetime_field, default: 0`

Comment: See adjustments to my answer. It does not modify the table, and it is not a raw sql. Are you allowed to do that? If not, why?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Looks like "default: 0" does what you want:

```
class CreateAnothers < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
    create_table :anothers do |t|
      t.date :start, null: false, default: 0
      t.timestamps null: false
    end
  end
end

 ➤ rake db:migrate
== 20150813201736 CreateAnothers: migrating ===================================
-- create_table(:anothers)
   -> 0.0943s
== 20150813201736 CreateAnothers: migrated (0.0944s) ==========================

[1] pry(main)> Another.create
   (0.2ms)  BEGIN
  SQL (0.5ms)  INSERT INTO `anothers` (`created_at`, `updated_at`) VALUES ('2015-08-13 20:19:02', '2015-08-13 20:19:02')
   (34.6ms)  COMMIT
=> #<Another:0x0000000ab8eb38 id: 1, start: nil, created_at: Thu, 13 Aug 2015 15:19:02 CDT -05:00, updated_at: Thu, 13 Aug 2015 15:19:02 CDT -05:00>

mysql> select * from anothers;
+----+------------+---------------------+---------------------+
| id | start      | created_at          | updated_at          |
+----+------------+---------------------+---------------------+
|  1 | 0000-00-00 | 2015-08-13 20:20:14 | 2015-08-13 20:20:14 |
+----+------------+---------------------+---------------------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)
```

**After clarification of requirements**

So, in other words what is your goal? You want to run update through rails to modify your table? If so, you can do

```
 ActiveRecord::Base.connection.execute("UPDATE table SET field='0000-00-00' WHERE id=#{self.id}")
```

Is it allowed? (YES)

**Update**

Ok, if you want it pure Rails, so be it:

```
[5] pry(main)> a.update_attribute(:start, nil)
   (1.5ms)  BEGIN
  SQL (3.6ms)  UPDATE `anothers` SET `start` = NULL, `updated_at` = '2015-08-14 16:31:22' WHERE `anothers`.`id` = 1
   (36.8ms)  COMMIT
=> true
[6] pry(main)> a.update_attribute(:start, "0000-00-00")
   (0.2ms)  BEGIN
   (0.1ms)  COMMIT
=> true

mysql> select * from anothers;
+----+-------+---------------------+---------------------+
| id | start | created_at          | updated_at          |
+----+-------+---------------------+---------------------+
|  1 | NULL  | 2015-08-14 16:30:39 | 2015-08-14 16:31:22 |
+----+-------+---------------------+---------------------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)
```

As you can see update_attribute does not work, but

```
[8] pry(main)> a.update_column(:start, "0000-00-00")
  SQL (47.1ms)  UPDATE `anothers` SET `anothers`.`start` = '0000-00-00' WHERE `anothers`.`id` = 1
=> true

mysql> select * from anothers;
+----+------------+---------------------+---------------------+
| id | start      | created_at          | updated_at          |
+----+------------+---------------------+---------------------+
|  1 | 0000-00-00 | 2015-08-14 16:30:39 | 2015-08-14 16:31:22 |
+----+------------+---------------------+---------------------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)
```

**update_column** does!

Note here, that after you do `a.update_column(:start, "0000-00-00")`, the date field on your variable (in my case "a.start") will be set to "0000-00-00". And if you want it show the actual nil value, you will need to reload it, like `a.reload`.

Comment: I should have clarified...I'm not able to modify my SQL database to make this work. Thanks for the good answer, but it unfortunately won't work for me.

Comment: @BenVisness: "I'm not able to modify my SQL database to make this work" is a bad clarification. Do you get any errors? Do you know what MySql version are you running? It clearly works, so show me the same steps as I did on my database, and we will see which part does not work. I do not accept statements "it does work" without "...because..."

Comment: Your answer is a perfectly good one, but I just had forgotten to clarify that extra condition. I've upvoted it since I think other people would find it very helpful, but it just doesn't work in my specific case.

Comment: @BenVisness: What does it mean "I am not allowed to". Not allowed to do what? Migrations? Column modifications? What is the set of actions that you are allowed to do? You said you can run SQL on it? Can you ran migrations? Does this column exists currently and you just need to modify it to accept _0000-00-00_? You never mentioned any access limitations or something.

Comment: I was perfectly clear - I am not allowed to alter the structure of this SQL database in any way. It's our company's main product database with all our user data in it, and I'm not an employee who is allowed to change that structure.

Besides, the column already accepts 0000-00-00, and I can insert it using `UPDATE table SET field=0000-00-00 WHERE id=#{self.id}`. I just would like to know if it's possible *without the raw SQL*.

Comment: You modified you EDIT just about 10 minutes ago, before it stated "I am not able", so my answer is 100% legit. So, in other words what is your goal? You want to run update through rails to modify your table? If so, you can do ActiveRecord::Base.connection.execute("UPDATE table SET field='0000-00-00' WHERE id=?", self.id). Is it allowed?

Comment: Yes, that second method is allowed. But I would prefer not to make the query using SQL syntax, and I'm instead wondering if there is a way to handle this change without writing out SQL (even in Ruby).

Comment: @BenVisness: Ok, you have it without SQL. Pure Rails way. I updated my answer.

Answer (score -1):

I guess this does not work with a proper gregorian calendar, since there is no year 0: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/0_(year)

Maybe try year 01-01-0001 instead.

Comment: No, that won't work, because I need to set it to the actual zero date. And I think DateTime.parse() still chokes on that date as well.